# Bug in ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I want to check if this is a bug before I email WR about it.

I can't get ListPlot[] to make scatter plots over a very small area:

```
n = 40;
c = I + RandomReal[1, n]*(2^-48)*Exp[I*Pi*2*RandomReal[1, n]];
ListPlot[Transpose[{Re[c], Im[c]}]]
```

[image: BadScatterPlot]

Providing an explicit PlotRange returns the exact same plot:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{Re[c], Im[c]}], PlotRange -> {{Min[Re[c]], Max[Re[c]]}, {Min[Im[c]], Max[Im[c]]}}]
```

Subtracting I from c as a workaround yields a plot, but I shouldn't have to do this:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{Re[c], Im[c - I]}]]
```

[image: cMinusI]

Is this a bug, or is there some quirk of ListPlot[] that I'm not aware of?  Thanks.

Comment: At least when I try this, `Im[c]` evaluates to 1.0 for all `c`. Are you sure you're not in some sort of machine-precision-limited situation here?

Comment: @flip  Is it just displaying as 1?  Try subtracting 1 from Im[c], and try Im[c-i].  This this was just a precision error, my second plot would fail.

Comment: In short, `Im[c] - I` is a complex number, however you may probably want to plot this: `Im[c-I]`.

Comment: +1. Except for the typo of the input, it's a valuable question. Since 2^-48 > 2^-53, there is no reason for the lost of the precision. The plot range issue also happens to `Plot` etc.. Quite weird.

Comment: @luyuwuli  Thank you.  But what typo in the input?  Did you fix it?

Comment: @JerryGuern I mean the blank plot is due to the typo :`Transpose[{Re[c], Im[c]-I}]`, you need to change it to `Transpose[{Re[c], Im[c - I]}]`.

Comment: @luyuwuli  Oh, you're right!  Good catch.  I'll fix that right away.

Comment: Good point Jerry, of course you're right- indeed the numbers are 'there'. `First@c // FullForm` is `Complex[1.1713011483818409\`*^-15,1.0000000000000007\`]` I wonder if it does something with the Min/Max of the x-y ranges where the difference (6.32827*10^-15 for example) gets clobbered. The ratio of the Re/Im in this case is pretty close to 1 so I can't quite figure what is up there either.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of `ListPlot`. It tries to avoid generating graphics where all the ticks would look the same ("1", in this case.)